# Generate a matrix of TextBoxes

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to generate dynamically a matrix of TextBoxes in a Form. In the row
    textbox[i][j].Size = new Size(w,h); 
I get the error "NullReferenceException".

```
TextBox[][] textbox = new TextBox[100][];
        int x_point = 70;
        int y_point = 70;
        int h = 30;
        int w = 40;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_columns; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < number_columns; j++)
            {
                textbox[i][j] = new TextBox();
                textbox[i][j].Size = new Size(h, w); // Here I get the error
                textbox[i][j].Location = new Point(x_point, y_point);
                y_point = y_point + 40;
                this.Controls.Add(textbox[i][j]);
            }
            y_point = 70;
            x_point =x_point + 30;
        }
```

Comment: Array are zero-based in c#! So change the loops to `for (int i = 0; i < number_columns; i++)` etc..

Comment: I changed it, but it isn't working :(

Comment: And, of course you need the right upper limit. is it 100 or number_columns??? Also the inner dimension is not even set up..  Maybe you want: `TextBox[][] textbox = new TextBox[number_cols][number_rows];` ?? .  Also: Do use the debugger before coming here!!! - Also you ought to get the error one line earlier!?!

Comment: What is the value of `number_columns`?  Did you mean to use `number_columns` on both the `i` loop and `j` loop?  Is there a `number_rows` variable by chance?  What are the values of `i` and `j` when the exception occurs?

Comment: it is NxN matrix, the number of columns is equal to number of rows, and I named it number_columns

Comment: at the first iteration the error occurs, when i=j=0

Comment: So you want `TextBox[,] textbox = new TextBox[100,100];` ! Btw: 10k TextBoxes will result in a terrible performance! Usually a DataGridView is called for..

Comment: TextBox[][] textbox = new TextBox[number_cols][number_rows]; I cannot complete the number_rows field, I get the error : Invalid rank specifier.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Your code was setting up a __jagged__ array but you really want a __2d array__. Jagged arrays can have __varying element count__ in the 2nd dimension so the size can't be set up. See my last comment!!

Comment: TaW, Yes that is what I want, but what is the difference between them?

Comment: Beyond the last comment see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

Comment: Thank you TaW, I understood .